# Edit value in treeview and update

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to find out as no specific question is related to this and there is no real helpful answer.
I have a Treeview opening from a SQL database and I want the quantity in the view to be editable.

It basically consists out of 5 columns and only the contents under the one column head named "QTY" should be editable as it is items that are counted.

The new qty should then be updated to display as the input by the user.

There are many rows to edit so to write and set a separate program for each row would be unnecessary and just look like terribly written code.

Comment: Update the source data then delete the treeview and repopulate it.

Comment: The source data gets updated with a different tkinter, but I want to achieve a different goal with the editing of individual quantities inside the treeview, instead of having to do it through another tkinter as it would take too long. (There is 583 rows in the list)

Comment: You may be able to use get_children() to locate your row and edit that row and changing the values. Look at this post it might help you with your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32516406/7475225

Comment: @Mike-SMT What i would want ideally is to have the treeview showing as i run the program. I can then just double click on a value in the Quantity column and then UPDATE that value in the database. I have the information read from a database, so any alteration to the physical layout of the database and rows/columns it contains will be done in SQL itself. The above article is similar to a normal UPDATE function as I understand. I would actually prefer to edit the value in the treeview, as metioned above. Thank you