# How can I delete text from TreeView grid that is recently added?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9r6z.png)

The user Insert text in TreeView and hit upload
then that text appended in the grid of TreeView
how can i reset the grid empty

Comment: ```tree.delete(*tree.get_children())```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete and Edit items in TreeView Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511843/delete-and-edit-items-in-treeview-tkinter)

Comment: It seems like you can answer this by reading available documentation. Can you show what you've tried? It's not clear why you need our help.